# Data error(cyclic redundancy check) while logging transaction status using bitronix transaction manager

Tags: crc, bitronix

Below exception occurred. Any possible explanations. My notion is may be problem with filesystem!?

```
Caused by: bitronix.tm.internal.BitronixSystemException: error logging status
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.setStatus(BitronixTransaction.java:400)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.setStatus(BitronixTransaction.java:379)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.setActive(BitronixTransaction.java:367)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager.begin(BitronixTransactionManager.java:126)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Data error (cyclic redundancy check)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write(FileDispatcherImpl.java:71)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:89)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:60)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:195)
    at bitronix.tm.journal.TransactionLogAppender.writeLog(TransactionLogAppender.java:121)
    at bitronix.tm.journal.DiskJournal.log(DiskJournal.java:98)
    at bitronix.tm.BitronixTransaction.setStatus(BitronixTransaction.java:389)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons for such problem: a bug in the BTM disk journal or a hardware failure (could be RAM, disk, power supply, motherboard... almost anything).

Since the Disk journal is IMHO quite a solid piece of software that has been running on many production systems for years, I'd rather suspect your hardware first.